# Email Notification On Low stock, Out of stock , Back to stock Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email, out-of-stock, stock-status, adminnotification

I want to create a stock alert where user can subscribe

`product_alert_stock` table in the database store details when user click on subscribe link.

Currently it sends on two conditions : On `stock change` and `Price change`.

**I want to send email if stock goes below a fixed quantity.**

For this i created an `custom attribute` namely  `send_mail_qty`

It must send an email to the customer when a product is below a fixed quantity

i created a `custom module` and using event ``
in `config.xml`

```
  <events>
      <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>customalert/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>stockChange</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
    </events>
```

In `observer.php`

```
        public function stockChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {

             $arg_attribute          = 'send_mail_qty';
$attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
$attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

$attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
$attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

$attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
$options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions();

            Mage::log( 'start');
            Mage::log( $options );
            // Mage::log( print_r($val) );

            Mage::log( 'end');


        }
```

}

But it gives me

```
2017-10-13T06:26:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): start
2017-10-13T06:26:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => 
            [value] => 
        )

)

2017-10-13T06:26:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): end
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento Default provide product alert module so configure phtml file as per your requirement.You don't need to create custom module for it.

Read Magento Doc
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-product-alert.html

Comment: i want to send email when stock goes below a fix quantity

Comment: can you check why my custom div not shown on view page. I copied same core file

Comment: Hi @SaurabhRanjan ,there is already option in magento.Go to System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options section section and check product stock option "Notify for Quantity Below".

Comment: i want to send mail even when a product quantity is below a fixed number